# Are there any responsive image scripts/frameworks that are fully front-end?

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, responsive-design

I've seen a number of methods for [responsive images](http://adactio.com/journal/4997/) that use some combination of modifying the .htaccess file (requires apache) or a php file (require php). I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a good technique for handling this issue that requires only html/css/js.

I am aware a *complete* solution (that only loads the specifically required images and nothing extra) might not be possible, so for this I'd also accept a simple/intuitive system that loads the smallest version by default but replaces with larger one

(It's not a hugely difficult thing to code; I am wondering if there are any 'common' ways of doing it in a really badass, clean, elegant way.)

Answer (score 1):

I tested http://www.headlondon.com/our-thoughts/technology/posts/creating-responsive-images-using-the-noscript-tag which worked for me. I just used the jquery script which is in the github repo - https://github.com/futurechimp/responsive_image_tag/blob/master/lib/generators/responsive_image_tag/templates/responsive-image-tag-jquery.js